# Is there a way to use GLSL in a Live Wallpaper on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, view, glsl, live-wallpaper

So I used the code [here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers) to first initialize the OpenGL in my Live Wallpaper. But now I need to activate the GLSL, but there's no way to activate the it because the function `setEGLContextClientVersion` is missing.

Another solution would be to be able to put a view in a Live Wallpaper, being able to use `GLSurfaceView` would solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [ghisguth / blurred-lines-live](https://github.com/ghisguth/blurred-lines-live).

> Blurred Lines Live Wallpaper for android OpenGL ES 2.0 capable device

- [Wallpaper.java](https://github.com/ghisguth/blurred-lines-live/blob/master/src/cxa/lineswallpaper/Wallpaper.java) - initialize GLSurfaceView for OpenGL ES 2.0
- [GLES20LinesRenderer.java](https://github.com/ghisguth/blurred-lines-live/blob/master/src/cxa/lineswallpaper/GLES20LinesRenderer.java) - GLSL shaders